# Hanging Drywall vs Bad Framing

Tags: drywall, framing, basement-refinishing

I am in the process of hanging drywall in my basement.
The builder actually framed my perimeter walls and included batt insulation.
as I started looking at the framing I noticed the studs were at 24" OC but when measuring they were not. Moreover, the studs were are so crooked there is no possible way a person hanging drywall could do a decent job.
So as I started hanging the drywall the 8' piece was just short of the next stud so I had to stack more 2X4s so I don't have to cut the drywall.
Not sure why the framers dont take into account nominal drywall lengths.
So, with all my complaining out of the way are there any tips out there for drywall DYI people when they come across this scenario?
Some boards were so bowed I had to cut them in half and then shim the cut to make the boards straight.

Comment: Consider stripping the walls with horizontal 1x4 nice and straight and in 2’ layout then attach drywall to these

Comment: Did you start from the correct end? It could be that the layout was done from the outside of the corner, so it's expected that you'd cut the first sheet to length. Drywall is cheap and it takes seconds to shorten a sheet.

Comment: Did I start from the correct end? How does one find out which end they started at?

Comment: @ChristopherLond he means, your joists may only be exactly 24" on-center, starting from one end of your house - the last joist at the other end will be a little shorter, or sometimes a little longer... it's rare for every single one, to be exact as well, due to special features, plumbing and what not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One drywall crew used 1X4's to back the joints instead of cutting on the framing. They used 4' pieces, after they set the drywall piece in place, they screwed the 1X4 halfway exposed on the end, then set the next sheet to the exposed end.

Comment: This is preferable to zipping off the end of the sheet? I don't see how. More time, lumber, and screws.

Comment: In larger rooms it is about a wash time wise, no measuring or cutting just grab the precut 1X and set it in place. It is only 1X4 here and there... Then again everybody has there own preferences. I usually cut it to the stud, but the OP was looking for different alternatives.